# How can I use Blowfish cipher algorithm for securing FTP connection in a vsftpd service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I need to implement an SFTP server that uses Blowfish as the cipher algorithm for the communications. The FTP server will be in an Ubuntu OS. I initially installed `vsftpd` service and I'm trying to setup Blowfish in it but without success.

Is there a way to specify the Blowfish cipher algorithm in a `vsftpd` service or is there an alternative solution for this?

Comment: I need a SFTP server running for clients to connect and download some files. Based on what you commented, I need to implement it with OpenSSH instead of vsftpd?

Comment: Why blowfish? Blowfish is a block cipher, and I would have expected SFTP would use a stream cipher, but I may be wrong there. is there a good reason you would expect this combo to be possible?

Comment: @FrankThomas Blowfish is indeed a standard SSH cipher.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Is there a good reason you would expect it to _not_ be possible? Blowfish is merely a bad choice from the security side (and I think performance as well), but there's nothing outright preventing network protocols from using block ciphers; TLS and SSH have used e.g. AES-CBC (and 3DES-CBC, and Blowfish, and similar) for many years. They _can_ use stream ciphers, but don't have to. (And then there are modes like OFB that pretty much turn a block cipher into a stream cipher anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

vsftpd is an FTP server, NOT an SFTP server.

If you really want to implement SFTP (and not FTP over SSL/TLS – aka FTPS – what is commonly mistaken with SFTP), you need to use another server software. OpenSSH is a common SSH/SFTP server. And it's installed by default on most Linux distributions.